# NodeJS Request: How do I get `response.statusCode` when piping?

Tags: node.js, express, node-request

Sorry guys, I'm kind of lost. How can I console.log `response.statusCode` when piping?

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var port = 8000;

var destination = fs.createWriteStream('./downloads/google.html');
var url = "http://www.google.com/";
request(url).pipe(destination)
.on("finish", function() {
    console.log("done");
    console.log(response.statusCode); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< this
})
.on("error", function(err){
  console.log(err);
});

app.listen(port, function(){
console.log('running server on ' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to catch the `response` event from `request`. It won't be in the `finished` event from the pipe. You should also consider catching errors before the pipe. This is where you'll catch network errors. After the pipe you'll catch file errors.

```
request(url)
.on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode) // <--- Here 200
})
.on("error", function(err){
    console.log("Problem reaching URL: ", err);
 })
.pipe(destination)
.on("finish", function(response) {
    console.log("done");
})
.on("error", function(err){
    console.log("Problem writing file: ", err);
});
```